# Search word from a txt dictionary file in JAVA

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM8XP.png)I have written a program used to search the meaning of a word through a text file dictionary. The dictionary I have already loaded through the server side. I tried to through client side sending a word to the server and receive its corresponding meaning of that particular word. The message that sends from client side will like: "Search" + "Abandon". "Abandon" is represented by a String value word

The problem is as I tried to use "c.equals(word)" this method to find the word in the dictionary, it doesn`t work. But when I replace the String value word as "Abandon", the program works well. Could someone please help me to deal with this problem?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        int port = 3000;
        byte [] data = new byte[1024];
        byte [] datas = new byte[1024];
        String word = null;
        String Message = null;
        String clientMessage = null;
        File f = new File("dictionary.txt");    //load the dictionary
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        String c = null;

        while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waitting for a coonection on port 3000");
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new  DatagramPacket(data,data.length);
                DatagramSocket serverSock = new DatagramSocket(port);
                serverSock.receive(receivePacket);
                InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress(); 
                int por = receivePacket.getPort();
                clientMessage = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                Scanner client = new Scanner(clientMessage);  //deal with the message send from client socket
                Message = client.next();     //get the first token from the client message
                if(Message.equals("Search")) { //determain the funtion
                    word = client.next();        //get the word that need to search through dictionary 
                    while(s.hasNextLine()) { 
                        String a = s.nextLine();
                        Scanner b = new Scanner(a);  // Scan the line one by one represented by b
                        c = b.next();                // find the first word of each line   
                        System.out.println(c);    //print c
                        System.out.println(word); //print word
                        if(c.equals(word)) { //if the first word of that line match with the word(send from client)
                            System.out.println(a);     //print out that particular line
                            break;
                        } else 
                            System.out.println("b");
                    }
                }
            }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
          System.out.printlin("Wrong"); 
      }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any further questions please let me know.

here is the results of print c and word
A
Abandon
A-
Abandon
Aa
Abandon
Aardvark
Abandon
Ab-
Abandon
Abaft
Abandon
Abandon
Abandon
Abandoned
Abandon

From the result, we can find that there is a time that c and word are both "abandon"

As for the message that I transfer from client to server , I have added the sending message as "Search" + " " + "Abandon"

the screen shot of my result

Comment: take care of Java naming convention. variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: If `c.equals(word)` doesn't work as expected, just print out `c` and then print out `word` to see the difference. Possible cause is a whitespace, which can be handled by using `trim()` on the string variable.

Comment: If "Search" + "Abandon" is actually in your client code, the commend being sent to the server is "SearchAbandon" which won't pass the Message.equals("Search") check and therefor never starts the search through the file

Comment: Where is the catch/finally block?? :-P

Comment: Did you debug this first ? By printing the value your are checking ?

Comment: Hi, Juzraai. The problem is there is a whitespace in my sending packets. because I have defined that the data size as 1024 bits which will generate lots of white space behind my packet. How to trim these packets and send it back to the client?